# How to update this textField with the Date every second

Tags: java, date, jtextfield

I've get the Date, but it's static i want to get the actual date every second. How can I do it?

```
    Date fecha=new java.util.Date();
    textField = new JTextField(fecha.toLocaleString());
    textField.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 15));
    textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textField.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    textField.setBounds(362, 665, 300, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
```

Comment: Thread and while loop?

Comment: I've tryed putting the next code but isn't work

/*Timer t3 = new Timer();
     t3.schedule(new TimerTask() {
         @Override public void run() {
          //Here the code I've post before
         }
     }, 0L, 1);

Comment: @marcss that's util.timer not swing timer

Comment: and how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javax.swing.Timer` - Fires one or more `ActionEvents` at specified intervals

[refer java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //...Perform a task...
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

**Edit :**
If you need both timers in your code don't import both.import one timer.and for other timer use explicitly.import only util.timer an for swing timer use `new javax.swing.Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start()`

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, and with the code i've posted before into the task block, i can show 2 errors: The method start() is undefined for the type Timer, and The constructor Timer(int, ActionListener) is undefined

Comment: have u imported javax.swing.Timer class

Comment: no, because i'm using import java.util.Timer and shows me an error

Comment: yes, you have to import swing timer class, right?, if you are using my code.

Comment: yes but if I put import javax.swing.timer shows me that error: The import java.util.Timer collides with another import statement, because i'm using java.util.Timer too in other part of the code

Comment: refter http://www.mkyong.com/java/jdk-timer-scheduler-example/ it might be help you

Comment: @marcss because of you need both timer.don't import both.import one timer.and for other timer use explicitly.import only util.timer an for swing timer use
   `  new javax.swing.Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start() `

Comment: @FastSnail Thanks, thats the solution to my problem!

Comment: @marcss Thanks for your comment I am editing my answer with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using [javax.swing.Timer.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) as explained in other answers. Here is another solution using [java.lang.Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) :

```
new Thread (new Runnable(){
 public void run(){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
     SwingUtilities.invokelater(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
             updateTextField();
          }
      });
 }
}).start();
```

With :

```
public void updateTextField(){
   Date fecha = new java.util.Date();
   textField.setText(fecha.toLocaleString());
}
```

Comment: Now, The method invokelater(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type SwingUtilities

Answer (score 0):

The [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class provided by the `Swing` package should do what you need. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) Oracle tutorial should put you on the right track.